# Enable ChangeTracking for an Entity loaded with AsNoTracking

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After loading an entity using no tracking option can I enable tracking for that entity again?

Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what `Attach` method is for.

Comment: Its throwing exception saying entity with same id already exist in collection. I can post complete exception if you need.

Comment: 'I can post complete exception if you need'.  No.  Post a minimal, complete repro instead.

Comment: In case the context is tracking another entity with the same key, then you cannot track the entity in question. You can find the tracked entity and detach it, but that will probably break the navigation properties. You'd better not use long living context or no tracking queries.

Comment: Exception: Attaching an entity of type 'typeName' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.